# Running Python file from PHP return no output

Tags: python, php, linux, selenium, centos8

I have a problem when trying to run Python script from PHP file

the python file contains selenium that opens website and login .. etc

I don't know if the problem in my python file but it's working when run in by myself in the root
with command

```
python3 PUBG_Linux_no_bot.py 5397816510 1
```

this is my PHP code

```
    $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    $Plan = $_POST['Plan'];
    $command = 'python3 PUBG_Linux_no_bot.py ' . $ID . ' ' . $Plan;
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
```

this is python code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)    
driver.get('https://www.midasbuy.com/midasbuy/ot/buy/pubgm')

time.sleep(1)

print("done")
```

things I have tried:

change Permissions of PHP and py files to 755

chmod +x PUBG_Linux_no_bot.py

note: if I wrote only print("done") in python it's work just with chromdriver not working

Comment: The Python code looks incomplete. Maybe an error occurs somewhere before the code shown in the question.  The PHP code may run it in a different environment, e.g. in a different current directory, as a different user,... You could add more `print("some debug output")` to your Python script before the code shown in the question.

Comment: @Bodo no there is no error in the python file I have tested it alone by running it my self from root 
I just put the important part of file in the question

Comment: If you insist that there is no error in other parts of your script, then it is difficult to help. As I already wrote, the behavior of the Python script *might* be different when called from the PHP code. What happens if you insert a line like `print("before webdriver.ChromeOptions")` just before the first line shown in the question and a line `print("strart")` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: @Bodo 

strart
before webdriver.ChromeOptions

printed both of them

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your modified script and the output you get.  If you get the output of a `print` just before `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`, then probably this or some command after it fails and aborts the script. Please change your PHP code to `$command = 'python3 PUBG_Linux_no_bot.py ' . $ID . ' ' . $Plan . ' 2>&1'; and show the output in your question.